# Can pytest ignore import dependencies? I want to unit test Pi code

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am using a (as far as I can tell) Raspberry Pi specific library (smbus) for my project. I would like to use pytest to test the software both on my machine and with gitlab-ci on my school's server. Not that it matters, but this is for a club project not homework.

**A description of my environment:**

I am using Ubuntu 17.04/PyCharm for my development environment.
The gitlab runner that I have access to is docker based (I choose the environment).

Neither of the above two have the ability for smbus or the ability for i2c comms.

I am wondering if it is possible to tell pytest to ignore the smbus import without adding a try/except around the import?

Thanks.

Comment: What's bad about `try` / `except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to avoid a `try`/`accept` you could have a function return the import...

```
def get_smbus():
    import smbus
    return smbus

smbus = get_smbus()
```

This gives you the ability to use the mock library to overwrite the `get_smbus` function with ease.

But I personally would use `try` / `except` and catch `ImportError`.

Comment: Thanks. I just assumed that the try/except was bad practice.

Comment: try except is actually a really good practice - as long as you catch specific exceptions. Catching all errors and ignoring them is the bad practice.